# Function for permanently watching the system clipboard

Tags: emacs, elisp, clipboard, infinite-loop

I am just starting to learn programming so I hope this question is not too stupid.

I want to create a function for Emacs which permanently watches the clipboard of my system (in my case Windows 8) and appends every change to the current buffer of Emacs. This is my idea for the function:

```
(defun watch-clipboard ()
  "Watches Clipboard and appends every change to buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((old-clipboard)
        (new-clipboard)) ; two local variables for comparison
    (setq old-clipboard (current-kill 0))
    (while t             ; infinite loop
      (setq new-clipboard (current-kill 0)) 
      (if (not (string= old-clipboard new-clipboard)) ; check for change
        (progn (insert new-clipboard)
               (insert "\n")
               (setq old-clipboard new-clipboard))))))
```

Unfortunately there is a problem with this function:

The result is highly unreliable. Sometimes every change is yanked into the buffer but most of the time only half of the clipboard changes or only the last change are recognized.

Comment: Okay, I narrowed it down. Thank you, Thomas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be calling the [`interprogram-paste-function`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Low_002dLevel-Kill-Ring.html) directly, not via `current-kill`, which does funky stuff when it returns `nil`.

Also, I suggest [`sleep-for`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Waiting.html) to avoid a busy loop:

```
(defun my-watch-clipboard ()
  "Watches Clipboard and appends every change to buffer."
  (interactive)
  (while t             ; infinite loop
    (let ((clipboard (funcall interprogram-paste-function)))
      (when clipboard
        (insert clipboard)
        (insert "\n")))
    (sleep-for 1))) ; or maybe `sit-for` if you want screen updates
```

BTW, the code above could be simplified by [`awhen`](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AnaphoricLispMacros) (an [anaphoric macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro)).
Not that I use them myself...

Comment: Now the functions really works as it should. And I realized I need to study the documentation more. :) I even read about the _interprogram-paste-function_ and about the waiting functions but to my shame I did not fully understand it. Thank you very much! (unfortunately I lack the reputation to upvote your answer at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be good to have the final version of the function in this thread. (based on sds' advice; thanks again) So here it is:

```
(defun watch-clipboard ()
  "Watches Clipboard and appends every change to buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let (clipboard)
    (while t
      (setq clipboard (funcall interprogram-paste-function))
      (unless (null clipboard)
        (insert clipboard)
        (insert "\n"))
      (sit-for 1)))) ; screen updates are indeed better so I did not use 'sleep-for'
```

Because the *interprogram-paste-function* gives out *nil* after the first evaluation there is no need for checking if there was a change in the clipboard. Therefore there is now only one local variable instead of two. Furthermore *unless* only needs to check one condition. It is a little bit more slim than above and it does everything it should.